# cant instal tensorflow in conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I tried to install TensorFlow in conda by `conda install tensorflow`, but after about 3 hours, it finally showed these results and didn't install.
[here is a screen capture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcuFE.png)

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)?

Comment: Are you using NVIDIA/CUDA GPUs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the instructions from [the official documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)
Install the latest release of CPU-only tensorflow using this code:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

Or if you want to install GPU tensorflow, use this code:

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```